# How to alter invocation history with mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Note: mockito 1.10.19

The scenario is as follows; I have an abstract class as such:

```
/**
 *
 * @param <M> metadata class
 */
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public abstract class AttributeWriter<M>
    implements AttributeWriterByName
{
    protected final MetadataDriver<M> driver;
    protected final Path path;

    protected AttributeWriter(final Path path, final MetadataDriver<M> driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

The `AttributeWriterByName` interface is pretty simple:

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public interface AttributeWriterByName
{
    void setAttributeByName(String name, Object value)
        throws IOException;
}
```

An example of an implementation is this (the most simple there is):

```
@SuppressWarnings("DesignForExtension")
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public abstract class FileOwnerAttributeWriter<M>
    extends AttributeWriter<M>
{
    protected FileOwnerAttributeWriter(final Path path,
        final MetadataDriver<M> driver)
    {
        super(path, driver);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttributeByName(final String name, final Object value)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (!"owner".equals(Objects.requireNonNull(name)))
            throw new NoSuchAttributeException(name);
        setOwner((UserPrincipal) Objects.requireNonNull(value));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MethodMayBeStatic")
    public void setOwner(final UserPrincipal owner)
        throws IOException
    {
        throw new ReadOnlyAttributeException();
    }
}
```

The matching test file relies on an abstract class which reads as this:

```
public abstract class AttributeWriterTest<W extends AttributeWriter<Object>>
{
    protected final Path path = mock(Path.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected MetadataDriver<Object> driver = mock(MetadataDriver.class);

    protected W writer;

    protected static FileTime nullFileTime()
    {
        return isNull(FileTime.class);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public abstract void init()
        throws IOException;
}
```

As to the actual test class, it is:

```
public final class FileOwnerAttributeWriterTest
    extends AttributeWriterTest<FileOwnerAttributeWriter<Object>>
{
    @BeforeMethod
    @Override
    public void init()
        throws IOException
    {
        writer = spy(new FileOwnerAttributeWriter<Object>(path, driver)
        {
        });

        doNothing().when(writer).setOwner(any(UserPrincipal.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void setOwnerTest()
        throws IOException
    {
        final UserPrincipal owner = mock(UserPrincipal.class);

        writer.setAttributeByName("owner", owner);

        verify(writer).setOwner(same(owner));
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I have is as follows: I basically want to check that after the invocation of `.setAttributeName()`, nothing else happens *other* than `.setOwner()`.

But if I add to the test that I want to `verifyNoMoreInteractions(writer)`, this will fail since in this same test I invoke `.setAttributeByName()`...

Notwithstanding the fact that this is more than likely a problem with my design (I am still experimenting), is there a way to, for instance, tell mockito to ignore, somewhat, the call to `setAttributeByName()` in such a test so that I can write this?

```
verify(writer, only()).setOwner(same(owner));
```

---

**EDIT** What I'd like to be able to write, or the equivalent if it already exists, is this:

```
@Test
public void setOwnerTest()
    throws IOException
{
    final UserPrincipal owner = mock(UserPrincipal.class);

    ignoreInvocation(writer).setAttributeByName("owner", owner);

    verify(writer, only()).setOwner(same(owner));
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call verifyNoMoreInteractions(writer) *after* the verify call?  There are no calls to writer after the setOwner call.

Comment: @CarlManaster while this sounds like the thing to do, the problem is that the mock will also have recorded the call to `.setAttributeByName()`... Therefore this cannot work :/

Comment: Well, if you're expecting calls to both `setOwner()` and `setAttributeByName()`, then shouldn't that be what you verify?

Comment: @CarlManaster not in this case; the "user" here will call `.setAttributeByName()`; and depending on the first argument a different method will be called, and in this case it is `.setOwner()`. Note that I am fully aware that this is, at the moment, a design problem, but basically I'd like to be able to tell Mockito, for instance, to `ignoreInvocation(writer).setAttributeByName(whatever)` so that I can `verify(writer, only())` afterwards

Comment: I see.  I'm afraid I don't know of a way to do that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, see my simplified example below. In summary, you reset the mock prior to triggering a call to the real method.

I answered this as an exercise in fiddling with Mockito, but I hope it's obvious that you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this.

```
public class SimplifiedExample {

  class ClassUnderTest {
    public void doSomething(String value) {
      doSomethingElse(value);
    }

    public void doSomethingElse(String value) {
      System.out.println(value);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() throws Exception {
    ClassUnderTest foo = spy(new ClassUnderTest());    
    final String input = "bar";

    doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        reset(foo);
        invocation.callRealMethod();
        return null;
      }
    }).when(foo).doSomething(anyString());

    foo.doSomething(input);
    verify(foo, only()).doSomethingElse(input);
  }
}
```

Comment: "I hope it's obvious that you almost certainly shouldn't be doing this." <-- yes, I know it's a design bug...